# How to serve images which are outside the assets folder?

Tags: angular

### [my assets config in angular json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS7i5.png)

My code for accessing the images which are in root

[Preview image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmCL0.png)

---

My Folder structure

[preview of my angular app folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gur8.png)

---

### Error which i am facing while i am trying to access those images which are outside

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4bL8.png)

Comment: Can any body help me with this, i have tried glob in assets folder but it is not serving the images. Kindly help me with any alternatives

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're facing more in detail?

Comment: Actually i am trying to serve my images which are present outside the src folder of my angular project but i am unable to serve it, how to serve the images which are outside

Comment: If you another folder that contains images that  you want to use into your angular project just add the path in your assets array in the angular.json file. Then use the absolute path to load them into an img tag.

Comment: Is there no other alternatives, because when it is production we can not use the absolute path right?

Comment: In production I always use absolute pattern, but that's a personal opinion. Your image show that you have two folders selected in red. I don't see them specified into your assets array. Just add them there: `"assets": ['./uploads','./thumbinal']`

Comment: even i tried adding the same it is not working

Comment: You should add some code to that question, for example how you're trying to display an image.

Comment: src="assets/thumbnail/{{ item.file.fileName }}" i am trying to view the images like this

Comment: You can't use the "standard" src to load an image this way. Look the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine to have a variable in the ts file like this:

```
public myImage = "something.png";
```

in the html, to load the image in the way you're tryna doing it, just do that:

```
<img [src]="'./assets/' + myImage">
```

Comment: Then as I said post some relevant code. Most likely you didn't add the right folder in the assets array, nor your base is not src, nor the path in my example is not exactly the same to your situation.

Comment: You can't use `src="...{}"` this way.

Comment: i understood what you are saying but my problem is the images are not loading even if I use property binding. Images are present in the folders called uploads and thumbnails. I don't have any idea why images are not loading if our images are kept outside the root folder

Comment: What error are you getting in console? a 404 not found?

Comment: If you could do a stackblitz it would be nice

Comment: Kindly use this link for viewing in stackblitz https://aonirxmyl.github.stackblitz.io/. Thanks already.

Comment: The link is currently not loading for me. I'll investigate further when it will load.

Comment: Can you please try with this link https://nbwiyqvko.github.stackblitz.io/ and check

Comment: https://nbwiyqvko.github.stackblitz.io/home try with this link

Comment: For me it is working fine, i don't know why it is not coming

Comment: Maybe some ISP / nat problems. Can you do a repo on GH so I can clone it?

Comment: Kindly find the https://github.com/MurugeshAravind/zoom link for my repo